# #define xxxxxx BIT(0) linker error

Tags: c, gcc

I'm compiling someone else's code written in C using gcc ARM compiler for STM32F4

```
#define ESC_CSR_CMD_BUSY         BIT(31)
#define ESC_CSR_CMD_READ         (BIT(31) | BIT(30))
#define ESC_CSR_CMD_WRITE        BIT(31)
```

and I get an error as it appears to not know what BIT(n) is.

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'BIT'; did you mean
>   '__RBIT'?

is there a stdint file somewhere that defines what BIT is...? or an alternate way of writing this please.

Comment: it's easy to guess since two of them are setting bit 31, and the ..READ is a value with bit 30 and 31 set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code should ship with a definition of BIT, I would guess that this is a suitable definition:

```
#define BIT(n) (1UL << (n))
```

Comment: Thanks Erlkoenig, perfect answer!